# Running a gradle jersey 2.0 web app without a web.xml in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, gradle, jetty, servlet-3.0, jersey-2.0

I have a gradle project that I import in eclipse. The project is a web app and I manage to build and deploy it to the tomcat but the jersey REST services are not being loaded and hence I get 404 when trying to reach these services.

I'm using tomcat7 which has support for servlet-api 3.0.

please note that I'm not using a web.xml. I have a class that extends Application and should load the right classes and set the root for the REST services.
Here's my class:

```
import java.util.Set;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;

@javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath("api")
public class JerseyApplicationConfig extends Application
{
    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses()
    {    
        Set<Class<?>> resources = new java.util.HashSet<Class<?>>();
        addRestResourceClasses(resources);
        return resources;
    }

    private void addRestResourceClasses(Set<Class<?>> resources)
    {
        resources.add(com.cisco.gemini.LoggingRESTService.class);
    }    
}
```

The problem is that this class does not get created by jersey and therefore the REST services are not set up.

Thanks,
Gal

Update:

I managed to solve the problem so I'm posting here the solution for everyone's benefit.
Here's my gradle file that got things working. I can now build and run the services on tomcat7 from Eclipse and the jersey servlets load properly.

Note: I also wanted to be able to run the service from command line (for testing purposes) for this reason I applied the jettyEclipse plugin. The jetty plugin that comes with gradle does not support servlet-api 3.0. this isn't working for me yet (because of some conflict on slf4j which I'm using) but it might work for others.

Thanks,
Gal

```
apply plugin: 'java' 
apply plugin: 'war' 
apply plugin: 'jetty' 
apply plugin: 'eclipse-wtp'

repositories {
  mavenCentral()
}

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath (group: 'com.sahlbach.gradle', name: 'gradle-jetty-eclipse-plugin', version: '1.9.+')
    }
}
apply plugin: 'jettyEclipse'

dependencies {
  compile 'javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:3.0.1'
  compile 'com.sun.jersey:jersey-server:1.18.1'
  compile 'com.sun.jersey:jersey-core:1.18.1'
  compile 'com.sun.jersey:jersey-json:1.18.1'
  compile 'com.sun.jersey:jersey-servlet:1.18.1'  
  compile 'javax.ws.rs:jsr311-api:1.1.1'
  compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')    
  compile 'org.codehaus.jettison:jettison:1.3.5'
}

eclipse {
   wtp {
     component {
       contextPath = 'MyService'
       deployName = 'MyService'      
        facet {
          facet name: 'jst.web', version: '3.0'
          facet name: 'java', version: '1.7'        }
     }
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make it working from command-line you can try to use gretty plugin - https://github.com/akhikhl/gretty - it supports newer versions of Jetty including Servlet 3.0 compatible versions. Or the other way is to make your application 2.5 compatible: add web.xml and define various components here. I'd prefer the first solution.